# Dynamic page theme in nuxt.js

Tags: nuxt.js

I try to make something like dynamic page themes. Let's say that on start it will be option with 3 values: default, light and dark. I made 3 layouts, didn't set up bg-color in default. I explicitly set layout as default, but bg-color change to light theme (blue). When I specific bg-color as white in default, it stays blue. It's in dev mode. I can see in page inspection that they are defined both, and blue is superior.

What's strange happen from now. I deployed nuxt into container, and set up to be production mode. Problem stays, but superior is white this time. It doesn't matter if I set layout as default, or light.

Can someone tell me what I do wrong? Maybe layout isn't to this kind of things. I don't even know if changing theme (layout) without reloading page is even possible.